# Exponential Curve Fitting Python

Tags: python-3.x

Dataset with X and Y values and I don't know the function that describes the relationship. I want to determine the function that provides good fit in python. Shared the scatterplot with original data.

I have tried polynomial regression but reading about it shows that the data might over-fit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUrQZ.png)

This looks like a logarithmic function to me. Can someone help me on how to find the best fit for such a graph.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly=PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)
poly_data=poly.fit_transform(file[["x"]])
model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(poly_data, file["y"])
plt.scatter(file["x"], file["y"])
plt.plot(file["x"], model.predict(poly.fit_transform(file[["x"]])))
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50ngm.png)

Please let me know if you want to see the dataset.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far? Maybe we can adjust what you did so we can get to a working example ... together.

Comment: @cornel.raiu, added the code above along with the fit that i got

Comment: Scanning your image for converting it to data is not accurate enough. It would be better to post the data on numerical or text format.